# Magento 2 : X-Magento-Cache-Debug:MISS, over SSL, pages are not being cached by varnish

Tags: magento2, ssl, varnish, ubuntu

I have configure varnish with magento 2 with the reverse proxy in apache ubuntu.

But, when I see at the headers, I always get the header **MISS** from the host.

So, page is not being cached by the varnish. Also I have noticed that page speed is decrease after done the reverser proxy to work varnish over SSL 443 port.

Can anyone help me with this issue?